# Pandas adding computed column makes all values the same

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new in pandas and I'm trying to create new columns which is a length of `frame['sld']` and a number of vowels in `frame['sld']`.

The problem is that number of vowels is always 0 and length of `sld` is allways 10 count of rows.

```
frame = read_frame(Domain.objects.all()[:10]) 
frame['sld_length'] = len(frame['sld']) 
frame['value'] = len([x for x in frame['sld'] if x in list('aeiouy')])
```

where `slds` are `['google','facebook'...]` etc.

Do you know what is wrong?

EDIT:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame([['com','google'],['com','facebook']], columns=['tld','sld'])  
 df['sld_len'] = len(df['sld'])
 df['vowels_count'] = len([x for x in df['sld'] if x in list('aeiouy')])
```

Makes this DF:

```
   tld       sld  sld_len  vowels_count
0  com    google        2             0
1  com  facebook        2             0
```

Comment: `sld_length` is the same number for all rows because you are taking the length of the _pd.Series_ object and assigning it to each row. same concept applies to `value` since you are assigning it to a single value

Comment: post some sample data please and we can show you how to achieve the desired results

Comment: @gold_cy I've posted an EDIT. Feel free to check it. Thanks

Comment: can you try with  `df['sld'].str.count('|'.join('aeiouy'))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the built-in methods provided by [`str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) to get the desired results.

```
df['sld_len'] = df.sld.str.len()
df['vowels_count'] = df.sld.str.count('[aeiouy]')

   tld       sld  sld_len  vowels_count
0  com    google        6             3
1  com  facebook        8             4
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `.apply` a custom function so that it is applied to each value in the dataframe rather than the dataframe as a whole,

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['com','google'],['com','facebook']], columns=['tld','sld'])  
df['sld_len'] = df.sld.str.len()
df['vowels_count'] = df.sld.apply(lambda sld : len([x for x in sld if x in list('aeiouy')]))
```